# Preseed Ubiquity success command executed incompletely

Tags: system-installation, automation, preseed, ubiquity

I'm currently in the process of building an automated installation of Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. As custom command in my preseed file I'm using this

```
# Custom Commands
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command \
     string mkdir /target/install/; \
     cp -R /cdrom/scripts/* /target/install/; \
     chroot /target chmod +x /install/postinstall.sh; \
     chroot /target bash /install/postinstall.sh;
```

and `postinstall.sh` has this content

```
# Install Chrome
cd /install
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
# Delete Chrome install
rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

But Chrome doesn't get installed. The script itself is successfully copied to `/install` and also marked as executable

Hopefully somebody has an idea where my error is located.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :

```
chroot /target bash /install/postinstall.sh;
```

instead :

```
chroot /target bash -c "/install/postinstall.sh";
```

Following good for me(xubuntu 18.04) :

```
bash -c "/cdrom/tools/run.sh";
```

I use isocreator (cubic), if i want to add other deb files for my installer and I use preseed to install the system automatically.

Comment: I can confirm that this works well for ubuntu 18.04, paired with the question's commands. For me the culprit was first that I used `d-i preseed/late_command` which seems to be no longer supported, and then that I forgot the `string` in `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string`

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome installer could be asking questions, maybe add yes to your install command?

yes | dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

or

apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Answer (score -1):

It will not start automatically, you should put it in the rc.local in order to start after the first login in the background.

If you want to have it as part of the installtion process then you need to add the dep file to cdrom/pool/extras.

A quick solution will be:

**presseed:**
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
    cp -a /cdrom/preseed/install.sh /target/root/install.sh; \
    sed -i 's_exit 0_sh /root/install.sh_' /target/etc/rc.local

And in your script just remove it from rc.local when it is done:
**Script:**
sed -i 's_sh /root/install.sh_exit 0_' /etc/rc.local

I hope it make sense :)